# What's wrong with this screen

Tags: display, lcd, netbook

I have a Samsung netbook N130, out of warranty.  One day a kid sat on it and since then the display on the monitor is split horizontally. Each half is a duplicate of the other as you can see on these images (see the Start button).

My initial though was that the motherboard may have been damaged. But also thinking the screen may need to be replaced.

I know it is not easy to diagnose without seeing it, but have you ever come across this before?  I'm happy to take it apart, but not sure how to diagnose the problem.

Thanks

**EDIT:** I should have done this before, but when I connect this to an external monitor, the image is fine.  So could this be the connection or the backlight?

[image: Image 1] 
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's going to need a skilled hand replacing parts I'm afraid.

It's either the screen or the controller circuitry or the connection between the two.  Either way it's going to mean replacement parts I'm afraid.

Which is a shame - The N130 is a nice little unit isn't it?  I have one right here.  Goes everywhere with me.

Comment: As I said in the edit, it works fine if I connect it to the external monitor.  So I will probably check the connections first.

Comment: By "controller circuitry"  don't mean the graphics card, but the circuitry that converts the graphic signal into the displayable matrix data.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is liquid blending. It's when the trace amounts of liquid material for each pixel end up crossing their boundaries into the next pixel. It's technically what happens when you press on a screen and you see a wavy like pattern. When the actual pixels are broken or crushed, the orientation for each pixel goes out of whack. Your screen can still display things, but you will find that some colors will not display or look weird.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that many times on Lenovo ThinkPads, every time, it has been a loose cable vs. actual damage to the LCD. That symptom can also mean that there is damage to the controller or the LCD itself, hopefully it's the most simple and least expensive.